# What is the cheapest way to produce a lot of bass?

Tags: speakers

I'm trying to soundproof one room from noise coming from another room. I won't know how much bass will be generated from the other room until after the soundproof job is done.

So I want to assume the worst case scenario. What is the cheapest way for me to produce the maximum amount of bass? I don't need high frequencies, and I'm not particularly interested in sound quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well obviously to produce a lot of bass you're going to need a big driver. All I can suggest is trying to track down a second hand sub or bass guitar amp and running ultra-low frequency test tones through them at high levels.

Comment: It might be worth trying some of the non-ultra-low frequencies, too! I believe anything from 200Hz down is considered "bass."

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the amp or monitors that will be used in the room you are soundproofing? If so, generate a sine wave sweep in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) that goes from 20 Hz to 200 Hz. Loop it. Then crank the volume as high as you can.